# Android dragndrop surfaceview

Tags: android

I try to dragndrop list item which has surfaceview which show video. And for dragndrop I use code below:

```
 ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
 View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(mMainLayout);
 mMainLayout.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, mMainLayout, 0);
```

Problem is, when list item starts dragging, I see only black rect in surfaceview instead of last video frame.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after long research I find out of my problem. First of all I removed SurfaceView and use TextureView instead of it. Next when user start dragging, for me it's long click gesture, next code will work

```
ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
Bitmap b = mTextureView.getBitmap();
mDragImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(mMainLayout);
mMainLayout.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, mMainLayout, 0);
mDragImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
b.recycle();
```

I use getBitmap to take picture from TextureView and set it in ImageView, which is front of TextureView and set ImageView visible. After that, I start dragging main layout. Drag controller get screenshot with ImageView with last frame which I set up. After that I hide ImageView and recycle bitmap.